# Calculate Manhattan Distance and return lowest 3 distances

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100, size= (10,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['category']= ['apple','orange','grape','berry','strawberry','banana','kiwi','lemon','lime','pear']
```

I'd like to have a user select a category, say "Apple" and then have my function calculate a Manhattan distance between Apple and all the other categories and return the 3 closest values (the smallest difference). I'm not sure how to write a function that calls up the column in the dataframe, but this is what I have:

```
def Manhattan_d(category_name):
    return df['A'][0]-df['A'][1]+df['B'][0],(df['B'][1])+df['C'][0]-df['C'][1]+df['D'][0]
```

Comment: Do you want to compute a distance between classes? If so do you want to compute the distance between the mean (centroids) of the classes?

Comment: I'd like it to compute a manhattan distance between the chosen category and the remaining ones to determine which one is the closest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to compute the distance matrix:

```
def distance(row):
    cols = list('ABCD')
    return (df[cols] - row[cols]).abs().sum(axis=1)

df.set_index('category', inplace=True)
dist = df.apply(distance, axis=1)
```

Then you can use [`nsmallest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nsmallest.html) to extract the closest categories for the desired category:

```
dist['apple'].nsmallest(4)
```

You want to consider `n = 4` because the closest category here will be `'apple'` which is trivial.